# Change of variables formula for diffeomorphisms between manifolds

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

> Let $M,N$ be $n$-dimensional oriented smooth manfiolds without boundary and $\omega$ a compactly supported $n$-form on $N$. If $f \colon M \rightarrow N$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism, then
>   $$ \tag{1} \label{a}
> \int_{N}\omega = \int_{M}f^{\ast}\omega.
> $$

I want to prove (\ref{a}) using the change of variables formula in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which says that if $\psi \colon U \rightarrow V$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism between open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then 
$$ \tag{2} \label{b}
\int_{V}\eta = \int_{U}\psi^{\ast}\eta,
$$
where $\eta$ is an $n$-form having compact support in $V$.

*Try of proof:* W.l.o.g. we can assume (otherwise take a partition of unity) that there is an orientation-preserving chart $\varphi \colon U \rightarrow O$ such that $\operatorname{supp} \omega \subseteq O$, where $O \subseteq N$ is open. Therefore by definition of the integral
$$ \tag{3} \label{c}
\int_{N}\omega = \int_{U} \varphi^{\ast}\omega.
$$ 
On the other hand, $\operatorname{supp}f^{\ast}\omega \subset f^{-1}(O)$ and $f^{-1} \circ \varphi$ is a chart for $M$ with $\operatorname{supp}f^{\ast}\omega \subset \operatorname{im} f^{-1} \circ \varphi$. Therefore
$$ \tag{4} \label{d}
\int_{M}f^{\ast}\omega =  \int_{U}(f^{-1} \circ \varphi)^{\ast}f^{\ast}\omega.
$$
At this point I would be tempted to write $(f^{-1} \circ \varphi)^{\ast}f^{\ast}\omega = \varphi^{\ast}\omega$ and say the integrals (\ref{c}) and (\ref{d}) are equal, but I think something is wrong in this argument.
However, how can I rewrite (\ref{a}) to reduce it to the case (\ref{b})?

Comment: Note that in your "by definition of the integral"  you need to use the fact that the chart is itself orientation-preserving.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you, I corrected it.

Comment: Did you correct it both places? That's what is missing to make your argument correct.

Comment: I think in the second place we have that $f^{-1}$ is orientation-preserving (by assumption) and $\varphi$ is (still) orientation-preserving, therefore $f^{-1} \circ \varphi$ is orientation preserving.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Actually, I am trying to understand the proof of (1) which can be found in "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" by Lee and there it just says that (1) follows from (2) after choosing a chart like I did. (and the definition of the integral) But it looks like I did not use (2).

Comment: So now you've — quite appropriately — used the crucial hypothesis. The change of variables theorem is needed, by the way, to argue that your "definition" is in fact well-defined.

Comment: You are right, saying "by definition of the integral" is a bit misleading since one usually defines it via a partition of unity and an atlas, then one shows that my "definition" is an equivalent way of calculating the integral. Then one has to use the change of variables theorem to show that everything is independent of the choices we made. 

But do you say that my proof is completely correct now? I am still puzzled since Lee reduces everything to the case of Euclidean space and I did not understand how to do this and found this proof by accident.

Comment: Well, you've reduced it to well-definedness of the integral on an open subset $U$ of Euclidean space.