# Prescribing isometries

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f:M\to M$ a diffeomorphism. What conditions can one put on $f$ such that there is a metric $g$ for which $f$ is an isometry for $(M,g)$, i.e.
$f^*g=g$?

Answer (score 7):

If $f$ has finite order in the diffeomorphism group of $M$ (i.e. there is a $k$ such that $f^{\circ k} = \operatorname{id}_M$), then one can construct a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ with $f^*g = g$ as follows. Fix any Riemannian metric $g_0$ and consider the new metric

$$g = g_0 + f^*g_0 + (f^{\circ 2})^*g_0 + \dots + (f^{\circ (k-2)})^*g_0 + (f^{\circ (k-1)})^*g_0.$$

Then

\begin{align*}
f^*g &= f^*g_0 + f^*f^*g_0 + f^*(f^{\circ 2})^*g_0 + \dots + f^*(f^{\circ(k-2)})^*g_0 + f^*(f^{\circ (k-1)})g_0\\
&= f^*g_0 + (f\circ f)^*g_0 + (f^{\circ 2}\circ f)^*g_0 + \dots + (f^{\circ(k-2)}\circ f)^*g_0 + (f^{\circ(k-1)}\circ f)^*g_0\\
&= f^*g_0 + (f^{\circ 2})^*g_0 + (f^{\circ 3})^*g_0 + \dots + (f^{\circ(k-1)})^*g_0 + (f^{\circ k})^*g_0\\
&=f^*g_0 + (f^{\circ 2})^*g_0 + (f^{\circ 3})^*g_0 + \dots + (f^{\circ(k-1)})^*g_0 + (\operatorname{id}_M)^*g_0\\
&= g_0 + f^*g_0 + (f^{\circ 2})^*g_0 + (f^{\circ 3})^*g_0 + \dots + (f^{\circ(k-1)})^*g_0\\
&= g.
\end{align*}

Comment: More generally, if $f$ belongs to a compact Lie subgroup of the diffeomorphism group, one can construct the required Riemannian metric.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: I assume this is some sort of averaging argument by integrating over said Lie group. I'd be interested in the details if you have the time to expand on your comment.

Comment: I just posted an answer.  This is one of those "well-known" results that it's actually hard to find proved anywhere.

Comment: I don't have the proof for this, but it seems likely that you could do some similar averaging if the diffeomorphism group is amenable. Averaging g over larger and larger folner sets should work?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a proof of the claim I made in a comment on Michael's answer.  Namely, that if $f\in G\subseteq \operatorname{Diff}(M)$ with $G$ a compact Lie group, then there is an $f$-invariant Riemannian metric.  (In fact, there is a $G$-invariant metric.)

This proof I'll write below is essentially copied from Proposition 2.17 in the [Introduction to Lie groups, isometric and adjoint actions and some generalizations by Alexandrino and Bettiol](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.2374.pdf), so I've made it community wiki.  Their proof is stated in the context of showing that compact Lie groups have bi-invariant metrics, but almost exactly the same proof establishes the much more general result.

Suppose $G$ is a compact Lie group.   Let $\omega$ be a right invariant volume form on $G$, scaled so that $\int_G \omega = 1$.

Now, give $M$ an arbitrary Riemannian metric $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_0$.  We will define a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$ on $M$ as follows.  For $v,w\in T_p M$, we set $$\langle v,w\rangle_1 = \int_G \langle g_\ast v, g_\ast w \rangle_0 \omega.$$  Here, the notation $g_\ast$ denotes the differential of the map $M\rightarrow M$ with $m\mapsto gm$.

Let's prove that this actually works.

**Claim 1:**  $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$ is a Riemannian metric.

**Proof**:  Bilinearity follows because $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_0$ is bilinear and both $g_\ast$ and integration are linear.  Symmetry follows because $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_0$ is symmetric.  The fact that $\langle v,v\rangle_1 \geq 0$ follows because each $\langle g_\ast v, g_\ast v\rangle_0 \geq 0$.  Obviously $\langle 0, 0\rangle_1 = 0$.

The last condition is that $\langle v,v\rangle_1 > 0$ if $v\neq 0$.  Consider the function $\phi:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(g) = \langle g_\ast v, g_\ast v\rangle_0$.  This is obviously continuous and we know that $\phi(e) > 0$.  By continuity, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $e$ on which $\phi > \phi(e)/2$.  Then $\langle v,v\rangle_1$ is at least $\phi(e)/2$ times the (positive) measure of $U$.  $\square$

**Claim 2**:  $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$ is $G$-invariant.

**Proof**:  Let $h\in G$.  We need to show that $\langle h_\ast v, h_\ast w\rangle_1 = \langle v,w\rangle_1$.  To that end, we will use the function $\psi:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\psi(g) = \langle g_\ast v, g_\ast w\rangle_0$.

Then \begin{align*} \langle h_\ast v, h_\ast w\rangle &= \int_G \langle g_\ast (h_\ast v), g_\ast (h_\ast w)\rangle_0 \omega\\ &= \int_G \langle (gh)_\ast v, (gh)_\ast w\rangle_0 \omega\\ &= \int_G \psi(gh) \omega.\end{align*}

Now we are going to use the [change of variables formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300147/change-of-variables-formula-for-diffeomorphisms-between-manifolds) for the diffeomorphism $R_{h}:G\rightarrow G$ given by right multiplication by $h$, $R_h(g) = gh$.  That is, we'll view $\psi(gh)\omega$ as $R_h^\ast(\psi(g)\omega)$.  Here, we are using the fact that $\omega$ right invariant.

So, we get \begin{align*} \int_G \psi(gh)\omega &= \int_G R_h^\ast(\psi(g)\omega)\\
&= \int_G \psi(g)\omega\\ &= \int_G \langle g_\ast v, g_\ast w\rangle_0 \omega\\ &= \langle v,w\rangle_1.\end{align*} $\square$

Answer (score 2):

There are already some sufficient conditions here; here's a necessary one:

For each point $p$ such that $f^k(p)=p$ for some $k\ge 1$, we must have that $d_p(f^k):T_pM\to T_pM$ is orthogonal in some basis (i.e. diagonlizable over $\mathbb{C}$ with eigenvalues $|\lambda_i|=1$).

This is *not* a sufficient condition: the map $f:S^1\times\mathbb{R}\to S^1\times\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(z,x)=(e^{i\pi\theta}z,2x)$ with $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ irrational has no such fixed points but is never an isometry.

Comment: How do you know that the map in your last sentence is not an isometry of any metric?

Comment: @Michael:  Here's a sketch that $f$ is never an isometry.   Suppose it is.   By rescaling the metric, we can assume the closed ball $B_2$ of radius $2$ around $(1,0)$ is compact.  Select a point $(a,b)$ with $b\neq 0$ and $d((a,b),(1,0))\leq 1$.  Now, look at $f$-iterates of $(1,0)$.   There are infinitely many natural numbers $n_1,n_2,...$ such that $f^{n_i}(1,0)\in B_1$.  By the triangle inequality, $d((1,0), (f^{n_i}(a,b)) \leq 2$.  So, the sequence $f^{n_i}(a,b)$ lies in the compact set $B_2$, so must have a convergent subsequence.  But the second coordinate escapes to $\infty$.

Comment: (This argument doesn't use the fact that $\theta$ is irrational, but if it's rational, then Kajelad would have to worry about the fixed points of $f^k(p)$.  At these points, $f$ would fail to be orthogonal in some basis.)

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Jason DeVito's argument works. My original thought was that given a sequence $k_1<k_2<\cdots$ with $\lim_{i\to\infty}f^{k_i}(p)=p$, the existence of an $f$-invariant metric implies that sequence $\|d_p(f^{k_i})(v)\|$ must be bounded for any $v\in T_pM$ and any continuous norm $\|\ \ \|$ on $TM$.